# How do you create a data frame using combinations of character strings?

Tags: r, combinations

I am trying to create an data frame that is generated from combinations of a list of character strings in R. For example, the list would be something like

```
list <- c("liz", "doug", "stacy")
```

The end output goal would be a data frame that would have rows that allow for each combination to be present, such as this:

```
 df <- as.data.frame(cbind(c("liz", "liz", "doug"), c("doug", "stacy", "stacy")))
```

I'm trying to make so that each pair is it's own row, with no repeated combinations. Any thoughts on how to achieve this with larger character lists?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`expand.grid()` will give you all the possible combinations of its vector arguments:

```
number_of_variables<-2

output<-expand.grid(data.frame(replicate(number_of_variables, list))

>output
     X1    X2
1   liz   liz
2  doug   liz
3 stacy   liz
4   liz  doug
5  doug  doug
6 stacy  doug
7   liz stacy
8  doug stacy
9 stacy stacy
```

To have every combination as a column call `transpose(output)`

If you want unique combinations (discard those with the same elements), use `combn()`:

```
> data.frame(combn(list, number_of_variables))

    X1    X2    X3
1  liz   liz  doug
2 doug stacy stacy
```

Comment: This would just be for 2 variables, but this works well. Is there any way to remove opposite pairs that "match"? For example, rows that have Var1 = Var2 would essentially have the same information as Var2 = Var1. So the end goal would be to have just one of those two possible combinations in the dataframe.

Comment: what do you mean by 'opposite pairs'?

Comment: Pairs that contain the same information, just in a different order. So "stacy liz" is equivalent to "liz stacy".

Comment: Edited as requested

Comment: Awesome, that plus tranpose() did the trick. Thanks so much!